# AppDomains and licence files

Tags: c#, licensing, assemblies, appdomain

We have a dll which uses a third party component, with embedded licence file (licx).  now we are trying to use our dll in a windows service applicaiton, using mulitple appdomains. the code get compiled. but when im running it im getting an error message, saying cannot find the runtime licence.

could someone explain me this. when use the dll in a single domain it works fine. please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you creating the `AppDomain`? There is a [LicenseFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.licensefile.aspx) on `AppDomainSetup`; are you setting this? I'm not 100% "up" on license files and their use within `AppDomain`s, but that may help a little...

Unfortunately information on this area (license files vs embedded) looks very sparse... you could try copying the embedded resource to a temp file?

Answer (score 0):

If there is some static method/property to set then it is likely that you will have to do this per app domain.

I was under the impression however that licx files were only compiled into the executable project not into dll's.

Thus is your service is being started via a route that is not using the executable which had the license embedded in it then it will not get licensed. If you run the service but do not create multiple app domain's what happens?